# Unable to access Github through Browser or Console due to SSL certificate issue

Tags: macos, git, ssl

All of sudden I am getting following error while trying to clone repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/repo/xxx.git
Cloning into 'hits'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repo/xx.git/': SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I am also getting SSL error while accessing on Chrome Browser
[image]

This is what I get when get Cert details

[image]

I am using 10.6 OSX Leopard

Comment: I have same issue here. I can browse to github.com with safari and it loads the page without any errors but when i look the cert closer, it has the same error there: "This certificate has an invalid issuer". Also, I wonder why does safari in case of invalid cert not warn me in any way.

Comment: @dsomnus My biggest concern is that I can't use github anymore with SSL

Comment: @volatil3 I've added instructions that worked for me as an answer below.

Comment: @Volatil3 Could you mark my answer as accepted please? People seem to think it works for them. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The DigiCert certification has expired. These instructions fix it on OSX (taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/iHiD/3a3ee36df25d9f761723))

1. Launch Keychain Access

   - ⌘-Space
   - Type "Keychain Access"
   - Hit return
   - List item
2. Select "Show Expired Certificates" from the "View" menu.
3. Click the "login" section in the upper-left corner under "Keychains"
4. Order by Expires column on the RHS.
5. Look for the expired DigiCert certificate on the RHS. It will have a red X on it and it's expiration date is July 26th (or "today").
6. Right-click the certificate and select "Delete DigiCert..."

You may need to close and open Chrome to get it working again.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Here is more info, from DigiCert themselves.

https://blog.digicert.com/expired-intermediate-certificate/

Comment: Been looking for this solution for weeks weeks - the DigiCert issue affected a large number of things in my system including Git submodules. I was falsely blaming Yosemite Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted it out. I downloaded my required Certificate from *DigiCert* website and install in `login` section of `KeyChain`.